# Как задать ширину картинки не больше 100% от своего размера?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, вёрстка, изображения

Допустим есть блок div, в нём размещаются несколько img.
Как сделать так, чтобы если ширина img была меньше ширины div, то img не растягивалась, а оставалась на максимуме своей естественной ширины? Т.е. чтобы img не растягивалась по ширине div (если div очень большой), а оставалась на своей "естественно" стопроцентной ширине.

При этом **я не знаю фактических размеров картинок** (допустим рандомные с сервера приходят).

Для большего понимания наклепал картинку в paint.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Желательно это сделать без вмешательства js, но если без него никак, то лучше с ним.

Comment: max-width?. . .

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {border:3px outset green; margin:.5em 0}
.box1 {width:160px; height:320px;}
img {max-width:100%; height:auto}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/130/90" alt="" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/90" alt="" />
</div>
```

Что-то в таком роде

Comment: Все картинки в 1 div.

Comment: @ЕгорСпириади изменил..... Но в целом значения не имеет в одном диве или в разных. Использовал разные для примера.

Answer (score -3):

Блин, забыл что у меня margin и padding по нулям во всей вёрстке и из-за этого не работало просто выставление max-width: 100%.
В общем для меня вот такой код подошёл:

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Так в моём ответе именно такой код и был max-width....